# Do higher-tier monsters spawn at world creation, or only through evolution?

Tags: cataclysm-dda

What it says on the tin. I know I can control the rate at which monsters evolve over time with a world-creation option; what I'm wondering is, if I set this to zero, would I simply never see hulking horrors or bileous zombies or skeletal juggernauts or etc.?